# Can't access to nodebb after setting up without error on nginx + bitnami

Tags: node.js, nginx, nodebb

I followed the tutorial below except "Configuring nginx".
https://docs.nodebb.org/installing/os/debian/#configuring-nginx

my nodebb/config.json is like below.

```
{
"url": "https://MYDOMAIN",
"secret": "DEFAULT SECRET",
"database": "mongo",
"mongo": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "27017",
    "username": "nodebb",
    "password": "MYPASSWORD",
    "database": "nodebb",
    "uri": ""
},
"port": "4568"}
```

I set port 4568 because some other process is on 4567.
There was no error in setup, but I can't access https://MYDOMAIN:4568.

I command "./nodebb log", it says "info: NodeBB is now listening on: 0.0.0.0:4568" and never progress.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the port 4568 open on your machine?

Comment: Also, can you post your nginx configuration?

Comment: @gkivanov sir, Thank you very much. As you said, I didn't open the port. It really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open the port 4568.
And do like this

```
    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Socket.IO Support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```